# Conditioning on (random) sigma algebra?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I'm reading an article on stochastic localization ([here is the paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.04163)), and after defining what a localization process ${\nu_t}$, they give numerous examples which I don't quite understand.

The first example is as follows:
Consider a probability measure $\nu$ on $\{-1,1\}^n$ such that $X\sim\nu$, and to consider the process $\nu_1,...,\nu_n$ by first drawing $k = (k_1, ..., k_n)$ uniformly from $S_n$ (independently from $X$) and defining $\nu_t$ to be the random measure which is the of $X$ conditioned on $X_{k_1},...,X_{k_{i}}$, where $i=\lfloor t \rfloor \wedge n$. My question is how is $(\nu_t(A))$ indeed a Doob martingale, for any Borel measurable $A$? More importantly, how does one condition on a sub $\sigma$-algebra that itself is random?